# Android app closes on database connection

Tags: android, asp.net, sql-server, database-connection

I want to develop a simple log in program in android.I have created the database in MsSql 2008 and created the program for id and password checking using ASP.Net and hosted it using IIS.I can connect to the database when I run my android program in the emulator.

```
 HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:35654/SMART/loginserver.aspx");
```

Using the above command I can successfully run the application in the emulator.loginserver.aspx is the .net page used for contacting the database.

But when I try to launch the application from my phone (connected via USB) and try to log in using

```
HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://192.168.43.1**:85/SMART/loginserver.aspx");
```

where 192.168.43.1** is my IP address and 85 is the port where i have hosted the website,the application stops and i get the following in logcat

```
01-19 18:48:29.405: W/System.err(19966): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.43.1**:85 refused
```

Please help me to identify what i am doing wrong here.If I am not specific about something please tell me.I have enabled USB debugging and given permission for Internet in the androidmanifest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to get the correct Ip address from system using ipconfig by typing in cmd

Comment: I did.Its the IPV4 address

Comment: you cannot connect from 3G connection to local network

Comment: try to change the port number by going to adb shell through cmd prompt.

Comment: I tried with different ports.I tried 8080 also.Still i get the same

Comment: **are you using 3G connection on device?** if so **please learn some networking basics** you cannot connect devices from different subnetworks!  subnetwork 192.168.0.0 is meaningless if you are operate in ISP network (or means something different than in your local network)

Comment: I tried using 2g.The application still closes.(although it takes more time)

Comment: lol, 3G, 2G doesn't matter any  ... only same subnetwork(maybe WIFI) will work (or if your PC have some external IP, or use VPN) ... seems like you are really do not understand basics of networking

Comment: I am not good at networking.Actually this is the first application that i tried that uses networking.Can I fix it using VPN?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: I tried using wifi hotspot and gave the IP of the wifi adapter.Still doesn't work